# Publish to bintray a zip file with sbt-native-packager

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager, bintray

I want to publish a zip file to bintray using the sbt-native-launcher.

I am able to execute:

```
sbt publish
```

and it publishes the main artifacts (.jar, javadocs, and so on).

I am also able to execute:

```
sbt universal:packageBin
```

and it generates the .zip file.

However, when I execute:

```
sbt universal:publish
```

it gives the following error:

```
[info] Wrote C:\src\ShExcala\target\scala-2.10\shexcala_2.10-0.0.1.pom
tar: Cannot execute remote shell: No such file or directory
tar: C\:\\Users\\Labra\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\sbt_407249ba\\shexcala-0.0.1.tar: Cannot open: I/O error
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last universal:packageZipTarball for the full output.
[error] (universal:packageZipTarball) Error tarballing
C:\src\ShExcala\target\universal\shexcala-0.0.1.tgz. Exit code: 2
```

It seems that the problem is with the "universal:packageZipTarball" task which also gives the same error.

I am using windows and I have checked that I have "tar", "xz" and "gzip" installed.

I would not mind to publish only the .zip by now, so maybe another workaround is just to know how can I configure sbt-native-packager to avoid the packageZipTarball task.

The build.sbt definition is:

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._
import AssemblyKeys._
import bintray.Plugin.bintraySettings
import bintray.Keys._
import scala.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPlugin.ScalaJSKeys._

lazy val root = project.in(file("."))//.settings(crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.10.4", "2.11.0"))

Build.sharedSettings

version := Build.currentVersion

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "2.3.7" % "test" 
  , "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.0.1-SNAP" % "test"
  , "commons-configuration" % "commons-configuration" % "1.7"
  , "org.rogach" %% "scallop" % "0.9.5" 
  , "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.0.1"
  , "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.10.2" 
  , "com.assembla.scala-incubator" % "graph-core_2.10" % "1.6.2"
  , "org.apache.jena" % "jena-arq" % "2.10.1" 
  , "org.scalaz" % "scalaz-core_2.10" % "7.0.6" 
  , "es.weso" % "stateparser_2.10" % "0.0.1"
  , "es.weso" % "wesin_2.10" % "0.0.1" 
  )

autoCompilerPlugins := true

seq(bintraySettings:_*)

Build.publishSettings

deploymentSettings

publishMavenStyle := true

// publish <<= publish.dependsOn(publish in config("universal"))

packageArchetype.java_application

resourceGenerators in Test += Def.task {
  val location = url("https://github.com/shexSpec/test-suite/raw/gh-pages/tests.zip")
  IO.unzipURL(location, resourceManaged.value / "downloadedTests").toSeq
}.taskValue

resolvers ++= Seq("snapshots", "releases").map(Resolver.sonatypeRepo)
```

and the `project/build.scala` is:

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._
import bintray.Plugin.bintraySettings
import bintray.Keys._
import Def.ScopedKey
import scala.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPlugin._

object Build extends sbt.Build {

  val isRelease = true 

  def repo = "weso-releases" 

  val shExcalaVersion = "0.0.1"

  publishMavenStyle := false

  val currentVersion = shExcalaVersion

  protected val bintrayPublishIvyStyle = settingKey[Boolean]("=== !publishMavenStyle")   

  lazy val publishSettings = Seq(
    repository in bintray := this.repo,
    bintrayOrganization in bintray := Some("weso"),
    licenses += ("MPL-2.0", url("http://opensource.org/licenses/MPL-2.0")),
    bintrayPublishIvyStyle := true
  )

 val sharedSettings = Seq(
    organization := "es.weso",
    name := "shExcala",
    scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
 )
}
```

the output of `last universal:packageZipTarball` is:

```
> last universal:packageZipTarball
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error tarballing C:\src\ShExcala\target\universal\shexcala-0.0.1.tgz. Exit code: 2
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
        at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.universal.Archives$$anonfun$makeTarball$1.apply(Archives.scala:134)
        at  com.typesafe.sbt.packager.universal.Archives$$anonfun$makeTarball$1.apply(Archives.scala:118)
        at sbt.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:285)
        at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.universal.Archives$.makeTarball(Archives.scala:118)
        at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.universal.Archives$$anonfun$10.apply(Archives.scala:111)
        at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.universal.Archives$$anonfun$10.apply(Archives.scala:111)
        at scala.Function3$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function3.scala:35)
        at scala.Function3$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function3.scala:34)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
[error] (universal:packageZipTarball) Error tarballing     C:\src\ShExcala\target\universal\shexcala-0.0.1.tgz. Exit code: 2
>
```

Comment: Could you share your build definition and the output of `last universal:packageZipTarball` executed after `universal:publish` fails

Comment: I edited the question adding the build.sbt and the project/build.scala files

Comment: Can you please also add output of your `tar --version` and `gzip --version`. Additionally can you confirm you have no spaces in your directory/artifact names?

Comment: The tar version is (tar (GNU tar) 1.13) and the gzip version is (gzip 1.2.4 (18 Aug 93). I think that I have no spaces in my directory/artifact names...how could I confirm it?

Comment: This is not a solution really, but I think the problem may be related to the issue on how the tar handles absolute paths on Windows. What _sbt-native-packager_ does is executing `tar -pcvf C:\\.... destdir`, when I tried to run it on Windows it failed.

Comment: Yes, it seems so...and do you know how can I bypass the tar generation step? I mean, it seems that I can generate zip's and it would be good by now...

Comment: Can you open an issue for this on the sbt-native-packager github page? This looks like valid feature request (or bug)

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is with the `tar` for windows, which does not accept absolute paths. What *sbt-native-packager* does is executing `tar -pcvf <absolute-path> <input>`.

I am not sure you can easily disable `universal:packageZipTarball` task.

I can propose a workaround though. Install [bsdtar](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libarchive.htm), which doesn't seem to have this issue, and still can be called as gnu tar. Download the file from the link, and install *gnutar*, after installation go to *C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin* and copy `bsdtar.exe` to `tar.exe`.

Make sure the `tar` command is in your `PATH` variable.

Comment: Thanks...it seems to work. At least, if I execute `universal:packageZipTarball` it generates the .tgz. However, if I execute `universal:publish` sbt hangs up. I tried `universal:packageBin` and `publish` and they work as expected.