# sbt hangs up when publishing binaries to bintray

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager, bintray

I want to publish compressed binaries (.zip, .tgz) to bintray. I am using bintray-sbt and sbt-native-packager.

I am able to execute:

- `publish` which publishes the jars to bintray.
- `universal:packageBin` which generates a .zip
- `universal:packageZipTarball` which generates the .tgz

However, if I execute:
 - `universal:publish` sbt hangs up and I have to close the window in which it is executing.

Is there a way to execute sbt in a verbose way so I can see the logs or any other information? I tried to execute last, but as I had to close the window, it does not show anything interesting.

I have checked the dependencies of `universal:publish` (`universal:ivyModule`, `universal:publishConfiguration` and `universal:publish::streams`) and all of them finish.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy or something like it?

Comment: Not...in fact, what is strange is that `publish` works and publishes the jars in bintray. I am using the same configuration as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718949/publish-to-bintray-a-zip-file-with-sbt-native-packager)

Comment: Could you try with your `publishSettings` modified to include `version`, `publishMavenStyle := false`, `bintrayOrganization in bintray := None`? Additionally do you get to the point where you're being asked for bintray credentials? You can run in your sbt console `set logLevel := Level.Debug` prior running the `universal:publish` to get the debug information.

Comment: Thanks...I modified the settings you said and changed the logLevel to debug...the last line in the log is `[debug] Using inline dependencies specified in Scala.` just after the lines that show the packaging: `[debug] Using inline dependencies specified in Scala.`

Comment: You can also look at Artifactory logs (artifactory.log and request.log) to get some info on what's going on on Artifactory side.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this today as well (hence finding this question through a web search.)

It turned out in the end that it hadn't hung, it was just *really* slow.
`sbt` eventually succeeded after almost 4 minutes:

```
[info] published artifactName to https://api.bintray.com/...zip
[info] published artifactName to https://api.bintray.com/...tgz
[success] Total time: 216 s, completed 14-Jun-2017 10:22:06
```

It's likely that the universal binaries are a lot bigger than the jars, because they'll include all the dependent libraries as well.  (In my case, the ZIPs are ~20MB each vs ~60kB for the JAR.

How big are your ZIP artifacts?  And how long did you wait?